# if click then if click on nested div

Tags: jquery

I'm not quite sure how to click on a div that shows when after you click on the parent..?
Make sense?

Here is an example code snippet.

```
$('.item').bind('click', function(e){
var showme = $(this).find(".itemcontrols");
$(showme).toggle();
}); 

$('#add').bind('click', function(e){
alert();
});     

<div class="item ui-state-default">
    <div class="itemcontrols" style="display: block;">
        <div id="add">add</div>
        <div id="full">full</div>
        <div id="del">del</div>
    </div>
</div>

.item{display:none;}
```

Comment: I'm trying to click on the #add div but the parent div has a toggle show hide on it.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve.. The code as such looks fine.. Can you be little more specific on which div and what is expected?

Comment: this will help you : http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an `.itemcontrol` class to the children of `.itemcontrols`.

```
<div class="item ui-state-default">
  <div class="itemcontrols">
    ...
    <div id="add" class="itemcontrol">add</div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>​
```

And stop the propagation of all `.itemcontrol` elements using the [`.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) function.

```
$('.itemcontrols .itemcontrol').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});​
```

Apart from this, I would recommend you to use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind events, which is the current recommended way.

```
$('.item').on('click', function(e) {
  $(".itemcontrols", this).toggle();
});

$('.itemcontrols .itemcontrol').on('click', function(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
});​
```

[See it live here.](http://jsfiddle.net/2P2xX/)